# How to pad numpy arrays on all sides with 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to pad a 2D numpy array on all four sides with 0.

```
a = np.array([(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6)])
```

Comment: Use `np.pad`? -

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can use [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

You can use `pad_width=1` and `mode='constant'`. You can add `constant_values=0`, but since `0` is the default value this is not necessary.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(1, 2, 3),(4, 5, 6)])

res = np.pad(a, pad_width=1, mode='constant')

print(res)

# [[0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 2 3 0]
#  [0 4 5 6 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0]]
```